# No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'com.swiftyjson.SwiftyJSON' is correct

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, carthage

It's really bothering. I have several apps on the App Store, some of them use **SwiftyJSON**, but this latter one is weird. I'm trying to upload it to the App Store but I get this strange error.

> No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle
>   identifier 'com.swiftyjson.SwiftyJSON' is correct.

I have double checked project's bundle identifier it's correct, *com.myname.appname*. Also, it's correct on the **iTunesConnect** as well. I've read other similar questions, none of them helped. I'm using **carthage** and **Xcode 9**.

Comment: Looks like the primary bundle identifier seems to reference SwiftyJSON instead of your project. Are you building with the correct target?

Comment: Yes. I removed that framework and archived the app again, but this times it says ```No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'com.sabintsev.FontBlaster' is correct.```, which is just another 3rd-party framework I'm using. Is it a bug or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how these are related but I removed the `Info.plis` file, create a new project and replaced the app's `plist` file with this new one and the error is gone.